# multiple domains pointing to my elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ec2

I am hosting my website (currently in alpha) in Amazon EC2. My domain name still points to a launch rock website. Since I am in the alpha mode, my alpha users accesses the long amazonws.com address to login for now.

What I recently noticed was, in my error logs, I see at least two other domains pointing to my assigned elastic IP. I am assuming that my IP was originally used by other domains and they must have put a DNS entry pointing to the elastic IP address, which I am assigned to now.
Obviously, I don't want any website to point to my IP and hence my domain name. How can I get this fixed?

PS: I did type in those two domain names, which took me to my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent anyone from pointing their domain at your website. In this case it might just be an accident  (since the elastic ip's get reused), but in the case where someone is doing it on purpose your web application check the host name and redirect the traffic (or show an error page of some sort).

The methodology will vary depending on what platform you are working in (windows or linux).

You can also use rewrite rules to accomplish the same thing if that is more up your ally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would be able to do a redirect if it is other than my domain.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you could add a JavaScript at the top of your pages to check the users domain name. If they are not on the correct one, bounce them away from your server. Something like this...

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     var correctDomain = 'www.mysite.com';
     if(window.location.hostname!=currectDomain){
          window.location.href="http://www.microsoft.com";
      }
</script>
```

My JavaScript is far from perfect but you should get the idea.